# select all in Multiselect dropdown

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Hi I have a dropdown with checkbox. The dropdown list will be something like this:
* Select All
* N1
* N2
* N3
* N4
I want to select all the checkboxes by default. But when the user wants to select selectively, he/she has to uncheck select all which will unselect all the checkboxes and then he/she can select.

```
<select id="filter-select" multiple="multiple" >
        <option value="1">Select All</option>
        <option value="2">N1</option>
        <option value="3">N2</option>
        <option value="4">N3</option>
        <option value="5">N4</option>
        <option value="6">N5</option>
        <option value="7">N6</option>
 </select>
```

How to do this using Javascript/JQuery?

Answer (score 4):

Try using `change` handler with `selectedIndex`

```js
$(function() {
  var filter = $('#filter-select');
  filter.on('change', function() {
    if (this.selectedIndex) return; //not `Select All`
    filter.find('option:gt(0)').prop('selected', true);
    filter.find('option').eq(0).prop('selected', false);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="filter-select" multiple="multiple">
  <option value="1">Select All</option>
  <option value="2">N1</option>
  <option value="3">N2</option>
  <option value="4">N3</option>
  <option value="5">N4</option>
  <option value="6">N5</option>
  <option value="7">N6</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I changed code as follows.$('#nodes-select').change(function(){ console.log("Outside."); if($("#nodes-select option[value='-1']").is(':selected')) { console.log("Inside"); $('#nodes-select option').prop('selected', true); $("#nodes-select option[value='-1']").prop('selected', false); } }); But it is not working. console.log is printing correctly but the statements after console.log("Inside") are not working some how :(

Comment: @krish, Kindly update your post itself for the reference of other, perhaps changing the id should have work.

Answer (score 1):

Use `prop` to set the selected to true and in the selector you need to select all the options inside `#filter-select`:

**Update :**

Updated the snippet to check if the selected value is option 1 in select (i.e SelectAll) on select change event, if so then select all options and clear the selection of the first option.

```js
selectAll();

$('#filter-select').change(function(){

  if($("#filter-select option[value='1']").is(':selected'))
  {
     selectAll();
  }

})

function selectAll()
{
   $('#filter-select option').prop('selected', true);
   $("#filter-select option[value='1']").prop('selected', false);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="filter-select" multiple="multiple" >
        <option value="1">Select All</option>
        <option value="2">N1</option>
        <option value="3">N2</option>
        <option value="4">N3</option>
        <option value="5">N4</option>
        <option value="6">N5</option>
        <option value="7">N6</option>
 </select>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I changed code as follows.$('#nodes-select').change(function(){
            console.log("Outside.");
            if($("#nodes-select option[value='-1']").is(':selected'))
            {
                console.log("Inside");
                $('#nodes-select option').prop('selected', true);
                $("#nodes-select option[value='-1']").prop('selected', false);
            }

        }); But it is not working. console.log is printing correctly but the statements after console.log("Inside") are not working some how.

Answer (score 0):

```
var selected=$('#filter-select option').prop('selected', true);
console.log(selected.text());
$('#filter-select').change(function(){
alert($('option:selected',this).text());

})
```

[demo](https://jsfiddle.net/toqhxctz/)

When you select again the just get the new value